# Copy until the last piece of data

Tags: excel, ms-word, copy, vba

Is it possible to select a range to copy to the last item?

```
Sheets("Design").Select
Range("A1:C200").Copy

'My data only runs until E48 and Im left with 152 blancs.
```

So now it copies from A1 to E200, but how can I edit the above code so it only selects until the last piece of data, which in my case is E48? (this is variable)

Thanks!

@Jean

In my excel sheet I have data running from A1-A18, B is empty and C1-C2. Now I would like to copy all the cells that contain a value.

```
 With Range("A1")
     Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown).Cells(20, 3)).Copy
 End With
```

This will copy everything from A1-C20, but I only want A1-A18 and C1-C2 seen as though these contain data. But it needs to be formed in a way that once I have data in B or my range extends, that these get copied too.

Is this perhaps a bit clearer?

About the Copy/Paste situation;

I currently paste using this

```
appWD.Selection.PasteSpecial ' So it copies the formats too?
'In your case, do you mean I should do it like this?
Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown).Cells(20, 3)).Copy Destination:=appWD.Selection.PasteSpecial
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
With Range("A1")
    Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown).Cells(1, 5)).Copy
End With
```

Change the "5" if you need a different number of columns.

Also, this I learned the hard way: **Avoid Copy/Paste** if at all possible! Copy and Paste use the clipboard. Other programs may read from / write to the clipboard while your code is running, which will cause wild, unpredictable results. However, it's safe to copy to your target range on the same line, i.e. do this

```
Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown).Cells(1, 5)).Copy myDestinationRange
```

and not this

```
Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown).Cells(1, 5)).Copy
myDestinationRange.Paste
```

The latter uses the clipboard while the former does not.

Comment: thanks, so how would you reccomend this in my case?

So will it now go down from A1 to A5, or A1 downwards to E1 downwards? And this will only copy cells where there's data?

What do you mean by Avoid Copy/Paste? Sheets("1").Range("B1").Copy Destination:=Sheets("2").Range("A1").value

Something like that?

Comment: This also copies blancs, is possible to only select the fields that contain data?

Comment: So many questions... The way I use the Range property above is Range(UpperLeftCell,LowerRightCell). The entire "rectangle" defined by these upper-left and lower-right corners will be selected.

Comment: "> What do you mean by Avoid Copy/Paste?"   I gave an example in my answer... Do this, not this... Is it unclear in any way?...

Comment: I'll redefine my question above.

Comment: "This also copies blancs, is possible to only select the fields that contain data?"  It is possible, you'll have to use but another approach, too long to describe in a comment. I suggest you ask a new question with a detailed description of what you are trying to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338725/excel-macro-copy-a-range-of-cells-and-only-select-cells-with-data

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
a1 = Range("a1").Address
lastcell = Range("E1").End(xlDown).Address
Range(a1, lastcell).Copy
```

Comment: So it does. I've now fixed it so it does up to column E as the question said.

Comment: Doesn't this only copy A1-B1...-D1-E1:E48? In my case?

Comment: It copies everything in the rectangle from A1 to E48 in your case. If the last item in column E is E48, yet the other columns have data below row 48 then it won't copy those. Jean-François Corbett's comments about copying are worth paying attention to too.

Comment: Have another look at my post, I've tried to redefine it. This might be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If that suits you, my favorite is CurrentRegion:

```
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("a1")
```

Comment: Caution: if you have data in the neighbouring columns (column F, G...) this will be copied as well.

Comment: @JFC: Right, hence my warning "if that suits you"