# Copy a range of cells and only select cells with data

Tags: excel, count, vba

I'm looking for a way to copy a range of cells, but to only copy the cells that contain a value.

In my excel sheet I have data running from A1-A18, B is empty and C1-C2. Now I would like to copy all the cells that contain a value.

```
 With Range("A1")
     Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown).Cells(50, 3)).Copy
 End With
```

This will copy everything from A1-C50, but I only want A1-A18 and C1-C2 to be copied seen as though these contain data. But it needs to be formed in a way that once I have data in B or my range extends, that these get copied too.

```
'So the range could be 5000 and it only selects the data with a value.
With Range("A1")
Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown).Cells(5000, 3)).Copy
End With
```

Thanks!

---

Thanks to Jean, Current code:

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Integer
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
i = 1

With Range("A1")
   If .Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
   Else
     Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i)
     x = x + 1
   End If
End With

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

x = 1
With Range("B1")
' Column B may be empty. If so, xlDown will return cell C65536
' and whole empty column will be copied... prevent this.
    If .Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
       'Nothing in this column.
       'Do nothing.
    Else
       Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i)
       x = x + 1
    End If
End With

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

x = 1
With Range("C1")
    If .Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
    Else
        Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i)
        x = x + 1
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

A1 - A5 contains data, A6 is blanc, A7 contains data. It stops at A6 and heads over to column B, and continues in the same way.

Comment: NB: Your first code example will copy everything in the range A1:C67, not A1:C50...

Comment: your questions keep shifting after they've been answered and this is a bit demotivating...

Comment: I'm sorry :) but you"ve answered them all and I thank you for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your three columns have different sizes, the safest thing to do is to copy them one by one. Any shortcuts à la PasteSpecial will probably end up causing you headaches.

```
With Range("A1")
    Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown)).Copy myDestinationRangeA
End With

With Range("B1")
    ' Column B may be empty. If so, xlDown will return cell C65536
    ' and whole empty column will be copied... prevent this.
    If .Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
        'Nothing in this column.
        'Do nothing.
    Else
        Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown)).Copy myDestinationRangeB
    EndIf
End With

With Range("C1")
    Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown)).Copy myDestinationRangeC
End With
```

Now this is ugly, and a cleaner option would be to loop through the columns, especially if you have many columns and you're pasting them to adjacent columns in the same order.

```
Sub CopyStuff()

    Dim iCol As Long

    ' Loop through columns
    For iCol = 1 To 3 ' or however many columns you have
        With Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(iCol)
            ' Check that column is not empty.
            If .Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
                'Nothing in this column.
                'Do nothing.
            Else
                ' Copy the column to the destination
                Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown)).Copy _
                    Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(iCol).Cells(1, 1)
            End If
        End With
    Next iCol

End Sub
```

---

EDIT
So you've changed your question... Try looping through the individual cells, checking if the current cell is empty, and if not copy it. Haven't tested this, but you get the idea:

```
    iMaxRow = 5000 ' or whatever the max is. 
    'Don't make too large because this will slow down your code.

    ' Loop through columns and rows
    For iCol = 1 To 3 ' or however many columns you have
        For iRow = 1 To iMaxRow 

        With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow,iCol)
            ' Check that cell is not empty.
            If .Value = "" Then
                'Nothing in this cell.
                'Do nothing.
            Else
                ' Copy the cell to the destination
                .Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").cells(iRow,iCol)
            End If
        End With

        Next iRow
    Next iCol
```

This code will be really slow if `iMaxRow` is large. My hunch is that you're trying to solve a problem in a sort of inefficient way... It's a bit hard to settle on an optimal strategy when the question keeps changing.

Comment: this is almost perfect Jean, but once he sees an empty cell he heads to the next column, while there are still values BENEATH this empty cell. Edited main question with current situation.

Comment: i know, but this is more than suitable for now. I know my code won't be clean or perhaps optimal, but as long as it does what it needs to do, I'll be happy :P Your edit should work, seen as though it's going to loop through the entire column until a predefined value. Thank you very much for helping me :)

Comment: Just to add to this- if you don't want it to copy blank cells into your Sheet 2 destination, make a new row counter that only gets incremented in the `else` clause, and tell `Cells(newRowCounter, column)` to only paste with that given newRowCounter value.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the paste Special function. There's a 'skip blank' property that may help you.

Comment: Careful: PasteSpecial forces you to use the clipboard, with all the hazards that implies, as per my previous warning... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327265/excel-macro-copy-until-the-last-piece-of-data/5336542#5336542

Comment: Good point, Jean! Still, depending on the range size (specially the huge ones), I believe would be better to use the PasteSpecial rather than scan every cell in a range, right?

Answer (score 1):

To improve upon Jean-Francois Corbett's answer, use .UsedRange.Rows.Count to get the last used row. This will give you a fairly accurate range and it will not stop at the first blank cell.

Here is a link to an excellent example with commented notes for beginners...

- **[Excel macro - paste only non empty cells from one sheet to another - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495769/excel-macro-paste-only-non-empty-cells-from-one-sheet-to-another/14496277#14496277)**