# Selecting only Cells with Value VBA

Tags: vba

I have the code below and works fine, but I only want to copy cells with Values. I have blank data in the middle, as I will delete that does not make sense to copy them too.

```
Sub FindAgain()
'
' FindAgain Macro
'
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    AC = ActiveCell.Column
    Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells.Find(What:="Scenario", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, Cells(LastRow, AC)).Select

End Sub
```

Any idea how I can better write it? With Loop maybe? Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338725/copy-a-range-of-cells-and-only-select-cells-with-data   or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351245/copy-a-range-of-cells-and-only-select-cells-with-data-and-just-the-value-not-the

Both show examples you could use.

Comment: I think this can help! I maybe did not check properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that after `Range(ActiveCell, Cells(LastRow, AC)).Select` you see a region selected that you want to copy ignoring blank cells. One way to go about it is to iterate over all the cells in `Selection`, check if they are not empty and copy them:

```
Dim c As Range
Dim i As Long

' store current row for every column separately
Dim arrRowInCol() As Long
ReDim arrRowInCol(Selection.Column To Selection.Column + Selection.Columns.Count - 1)
For i = LBound(arrRowInCol) To UBound(arrRowInCol)
    ' init the first row for each column
    arrRowInCol(i) = Selection.Row
Next i

For Each c In Selection
    If Len(Trim(c)) <> 0 Then
        c.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(arrRowInCol(c.Column), c.Column)
        arrRowInCol(c.Column) = arrRowInCol(c.Column) + 1
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: That is very close of what I want. what happens with your piece is that, when it goes again, the blank line remains below, because and the data again below the blank.. so lets say, it keeps 1 blank 4 blank blank 5, what I want is to paste the data below each other 1 4 5 etc

Comment: I've updated the code to store current row for each column separately. You only increment it when you paste - so it effectively collapses every column on empty values. See if this works.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to do what I want: At least is working, i am newby so, for you guys may seem funny or bad, for me is great =D

```
Sub FindAgain()
'
' FindAgain Macro
'
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

AC = ActiveCell.Column
Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
i = 15
j = 7
Cells.Find(What:="Scenario", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Range(ActiveCell, Cells(LastRow, AC)).Select

For Each c In Selection
    If Len(Trim(c)) <> "" Then
        c.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j)
    End If

    If c = "" Then
    i = i
    Else
    i = i + 1
    End If
    j = j

Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I will start with your code, which actually tries to select the ranges. This is what I have built upon it:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindMe()

    Dim my_range            As Range
    Dim temp_range          As Range

    Dim l_counter           As Long
    Dim my_list             As Object
    Dim l_counter_start     As Long


    Set my_list = New Collection

    l_counter_start = Cells.Find(What:="Scenario", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Row + 1

    For l_counter = l_counter_start To Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(l_counter, 2) <> "" Then my_list.Add (l_counter)
    Next l_counter

    For l_counter = 1 To my_list.Count
        Set temp_range = Range(Cells(my_list(l_counter), 2), Cells(my_list(l_counter), 4))

        If my_range Is Nothing Then
            Set my_range = temp_range
        Else
            Set my_range = Union(my_range, temp_range)
        End If
    Next l_counter

    my_range.Select

End Sub
```

It works upon a scenario like this:
[image]

Pretty much it works like this:

- We declare two ranges.
- The range `my_range` is the one to be selected at the end.
- The range `temp_range` is only given, if there is a value in the second column.
- Then there is a union of both ranges, and `my_range` is selected at the end of the code.